# How should user agents handle unrecognized HTML elements?

Tags: html, standards, w3c

I have tried to find an answer to this in the W3C HTML specifications, but haven't had any luck so far.

For example, if I have the following HTML code:

```
<body>
    <p>
        <foo>bar</foo>
    </p>
</body>
```

Does W3C specify how a user agent should handle this? E.g should the "foo" element be completely ignored? Should the "foo" element be ignored but the content "bar" parsed?

Also, is it even "legal" to do this?

**Edit:** Some excellent answers from all of you! I totally agree that it would be bad practice to embed generic XML unless, possibly, if you have complete control over which browser your users will use. I was mostly curious about what actually would or should happen if such markup were to be produced :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some excellent advice from @Andy E. This is just some add-ons to that.

The HTML5 draft does define how to parse unknown elements, however, it is distinctly non-trivial. To see the rules, see http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/tree-construction.html

Note that the first version of Firefox to use these rules is FireFox 4, and the first version of IE to use the rules is IE 10. Older versions have a number of different and often very strange behaviours.

HTML has no notion of "legality", only validity or conformance to a standard. You are free to decide whether you want your pages to conform to any particular standard or not. There is no W3C standard of HTML where use of arbitrarily named elements is conforming.

It is generally advisable to make your HTML conforming to avoid unpredictable errors in browsers and other HTML consumers that you haven't tested against.

Answer (score 5):

The HTML spec doesn't say much about it, [other than](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#htmlunknownelement):

> The HTMLUnknownElement interface must be used for HTML elements that are not defined by this specification (or other applicable specifications).

This can be verified in conforming browsers using the following JavaScript code in the console:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(document.createElement("foo"));
//-> "[object HTMLUnknownElement]"
```

However, some browsers either don't follow the specification here yet.  For instance, Chrome 13 gives `[object HTMLElement]`, IE 8 gives `[object HTMLGenericElement]` (IE 9 is correct).

As far as I'm aware, all browsers will parse `<foo>` as an element, but default styling and behaviour is not guaranteed to be the same.  Where `HTMLUnknownElement` is implemented and the spec is followed, it should inherit directly from `HTMLElement` and, therefore, have many of the default properties found on other elements.

Please note that your HTML will not validate when you have non-standard elements in your markup.  It's also worth mentioning that search engine crawlers, screen readers and other software will not be able to extract semantic meaning from these elements.

#### Further reading:

- [Why generic XML on the web is a bad idea](http://annevankesteren.nl/2005/05/generic-xml) and [386: Generic Elements; Still a Bad Idea](http://annevankesteren.nl/2010/09/generic-elements) - Anne van Kesteren's blog (2005, 2010)

Comment: This is an old answer but are generic/HTMLUnknownElement elements still a bad idea?  I understand wanting to protect against future clashes, but it certainly makes the markup more legible.  It seems like using a name scheme that is unlikely to be adopted would be okay.  Would the appearance of these send the browser into quirksmode?  Also, perhaps the fact that they might be adopted in the future wouldn't necessarily be a *bad* thing.

Comment: @vol7ron: custom elements now have their own [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/), albeit in Working Draft status.  The idea is that custom tag names with a hyphen are valid custom elements.  If they don't have the hyphen, they retain HTMLUnknownElement as the prototype.  Browser support is very limited at the moment, though.  I haven't heard anything about custom elements sending browsers into quirksmode, so if you want to use them, then go ahead :-).

Comment: I assumed that when HTML was not valid (usually malformed), it automatically forced browsers into quirksmode.  I don't usually use custom elements, so never tested it, but I assume it is treated as *valid*, but renders as an `HTMLUnknownElement` as it should.   These days it seems to be better markup to use them, instead of overloading classes. --- Also, thanks for the link, I've read that once before, I'm trying to identify all the reasons not to use them (performance, browser handling, etc) as right now it seems like a legitimate use if you're targeting *newer* browsers.

Comment: @vol7ron: Another interesting point is that Anne van Kesteren's main reason for dismissing them as a bad idea was the potential naming collisions.  The specs outlining the addition of custom elements force you to use at least one hyphen in the name, which ensures no possible future naming collisions (presumably because all future standardised elements will never have a hyphen).  So, it's not so much a bad idea anymore, although consideration will need to be given.  I believe there's a shim for the Web Components API, too, which might simplify creating your own elements.

Answer (score 2):

"bar" should definitely be rendered. For example, in the HTML5 video element, the contents of the  element contain fallback content to be displayed in older browsers for exactly this reason. It's also why people traditionally put comments around style declarations:

```
<style><!-- 
  (styling goes here)
--></style>
```

to hide the styling information from pre-HTML 4 browsers. (I think the comments aren't considered good practice any more.)